# Necessity of comma

Tags: commas

Consider the below sentence:

> To my astonishment, he arrived on time.

One of the main purposes of the comma is to improve the readability of a sentence - to prevent ambiguity. Presumably, it is for this reason that a comma has been used in the above sentence. Yet its absence does not render the sentence unreadable - indeed, even if the comma were absent, the sentence would be no less readable than it is now. What, then, is the purpose of the comma? Is it merely a matter of personal preference?

Comment: Personal preference, and often to denote the correct pausing to be taken while reading the sentence out loud. In this case, the writer may want extra emphasis on the word "astonishment" , hence the comma after it, as opposed to the constant structure of the sentence without the comma.

Comment: In my personal experience, I have found it useful to read the sentence out loud with, and without the comma's pause to understand the slight difference in emphasis. (Not all writers add commas for emphasis, but it may be the case sometimes)

Answer (score 1):

In most ways of describing formal English grammar, that comma is just required to be there. In that sense it's not a stylistic choice; if you gave that sentence to a professional editor, they would probably add the comma. When you start a sentence with a prepositional phrase, like most introductory phrases, there should to be a comma after it.

Stylistically, commas don't just help with readability, they also often denote where one would pause in speech. In my experience, if a native English speaker were to say the sentence you provided, they would probably say it like: "To my astonishment [pause] he arrived on time." It's not a very long pause, but it helps break up the sentence and make it easier to parse. For me at least, if you omit the comma, I read it in my head like you're excitedly rushing through the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Consider if the phrases were flipped:

He arrived on time to my astonishment.

He arrived on time, to my astonishment.

Those sentences mean two different things. In the first one, he arrives to (at) "my astonishment" -- whatever that location or thing is. In the second, the speaker comments on the timely arrival.

I'm arguing that, without a comma separating the phrases, the "astonishment" is not a separate comment; it's the destination, the "arrived...to" object. That's a little far-fetched, but that's how reading works without punctuation -- things get tied together that don't have a literal connection.

And that is why it also makes sense for a comma to separate the phrases in the original order. The astonishment phrase is separate, parenthetical, a comment, an introductory phrase, whatever you want to call it, and it just reads better with a comma between it and the main statement, "He arrived on time."